# Permission denied writing artifacts to an NFS-mounted PVC

Tags: kubernetes, mlflow, kubernetes-pvc

I'm attempting to write MLflow artifacts to an NFS-mounted PVC. It's a new PVC mounting at `/opt/mlflow`, but MLflow seems to have permission writing to it. The specific error I'm getting is

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/mlflow'
```

I ran the same deployment with an S3-backed artifact store, and that worked just fine. That was on my home computer though, and I don't have the ability to do that at work. The MLflow documentation seems to indicate that I don't need any special syntax for NFS mounts.

Comment: NFS mounts have Linux file permissions and the user running in the container seems to have a restricted user id. Dependent on your settings, you may want to use `sudo chown` to change the owner of the directory

Answer (score 0):

Independent of MLflow you can approach this in a standard file permission way.

1. Exec into your pod and view the permissions at that file path

```
kubectl exec -it <pod>

ls -l /opt/mlflow
```

2. Within your pod/container see what user you are running as

```
whoami
```

If your user doesn't have access to that filepath, then you could adjust the file permissions by mounting the pvc into a different pod that runs under a user with permission to adjust them.  Or you could try using `fsGroup` to control the permissions of the files mounted, which you can read more about [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/).

Comment: Yeah I did that but unfortunately am still having write access issues. Not sure if it's because MLflow is specifically trying to reference something locally or what.

Comment: What do the permissions look like when you run `ls -l`.  Is your user permitted to write?